# Relacionar duas tabelas através de outra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo 3 tabelas, `processos`, `empresas` e `processos_empresas`.

estrutura das tabelas:

```
processos:
- id 

empresas:
- id
- nome_empresa

processos_empresas:
- processo_id
- empresa_id
```

Breve explicação de como se relacionam:

Um processo pode ter várias empresas, e essas empresas do processo são salvas na tabela `processos_empresas` com o **processo_id** e o **empresa_id**.

Atualmente dentro do **model Processo** existe um método chamado **empresas** que traz todas as empresas cadastradas na tabela `processos_empresas` com a relação `hasMany`, exemplo:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Processo extends Model {

    function empresas () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProcessoEmpresas');
    }
}
```

O que preciso fazer é, dentro do **model Processo**, também puxar os dados da tabela `empresa` através da tabela `processos_empresas` como já está sendo feito, basicamente preciso também da coluna **nome_empresa**

Encontrei na documentação o [hasManyTrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), mas não tive sucesso na implementação

Comment: Posta a migrations

Comment: Passa o model como esta na doc

Comment: Não entendi, postei a estrutura básica ali em cima

Comment: ```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the posts for the country.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\User');
    }
}

Comment: É mais que isso, seria uma relação dentro de relação processos > processos_empresas > empresas

Answer (score 2):

Isso seria um "many-to-many" (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Exemplo:

```
<?php
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Processo extends Model 
{
    function empresas() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
          Empresa::class, 
          'processos_empresas', 
          'processo_id', 
          'empresa_id'
        );
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Empresa extends Model 
{

    function processos() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
          Processo::class, 
          'processos_empresas', 
          'empresa_id', 
          'processo_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Desse jeito você vai conseguir:

```
<?php
// ...

$empresa = Empresa::with('processos')->first();
// listar todos os processos (ligados pela tabela pivot).
print_r($empresa->processos->toArray());
```

Comment: Ele retornou um campo "pivot" mas só com empresa_id e processo_id, como posso retornar outras campos? e como seria o uso disso se eu precisasse retornar através de um id específico de um processo? Ex: Processo::find(120)->empresas()...

Comment: se você tem outros campos na tabela pivot, você tem que adicionar no relacionamento `->withPivot('campo')`

Comment: `Processo::with('empresas')->where('id', 120)->first();` ou `Processo::with('empresas')->whereId(120)->first();` já vai retornar o processo com as empresas.

Comment: coloquei o ´withPivot´ no model processo e não retornou não, coloquei no outro (Empresa) e deu erro que a coluna não existe, estou fazendo algo errado? rs

Comment: Nesse segundo comentário, que busca o processo pelo id o resultado vem correto, sem `withPivot`